# create a Data frame as a function of row index value and column name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to create a pandas Data frame as a function of row index value and column name?

So for DataFrame where index in X, columns in Y, each value would be some f(x,y) where x in X and y in Y (eg could be concatenation of index and column names)

I know I can write a loop to do this, but figure there's a quicker way in pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension to prepare the values as a list of lists, and then pass the list of lists to `pd.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
rows = ['1','2','3']
cols = ['X','Y']

df = pd.DataFrame(([col+row for col in cols] for row in rows),
                  index=rows, columns=cols)
```

yields

```
    X   Y
1  X1  Y1
2  X2  Y2
3  X3  Y3
```

and of course you could replace `col+row` with a call to an arbitrary function `f`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(([f(row, col) for col in cols] for row in rows),
                  index=rows, columns=cols)
```

If `rows` and/or `cols` is large, then a list of lists could require a lot of memory. Calling `f` once for every cell could require some time. Depending on `f`, there might be a faster/less memory-intensive way to create `df`.
For example, to concatenate the row and column labels you could use `np.char.add` and `np.meshgrid`:

```
import numpy as np
rows = ['1','2','3']
cols = ['X','Y']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.char.add(*np.meshgrid(cols, rows, sparse=True, indexing='xy')), 
                  index=rows, columns=cols)
```

yields the same result.

This creates the NumPy array without creating a temporary list of lists, thus saving memory. Since `np.char.add` creates the resultant NumPy array in a vectorized way, if `rows` and `cols` is large, the result is obtained faster than computing `col+row` (in Python) for each cell.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I'm not trying to do a string concatenation- f(x,y) will be a call to difflib to see how similar the x and y strings are. I'm essentially trying to clean up a long list of names by getting rid of those which are (likely) to be duplicates.  So I guess the question is what's the most efficient way to call into an external function?